# Best way to collect a descriptive set of tags about a company from its url?

Tags: html, tags, metadata, data-mining

I'm pretty ignorant of what appears in the html/javascript of a website because I spend most of my time on the back-end (phrasing!). Basically, I want to know the best way to take a company's url, e.g. [PETA](http://www.peta.org), and from that url parse out descriptive words about the company from their front-page html. This way you can jump-start an auto-tagging categorization website with just a list of company urls.

If this is reasonable, any recommendations for tools/processes to find/mine the content would be much welcomed.

And if not or you have a better idea to get the tags, let it be known as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Swift is too correct -- if you're looking for categorization only, then all you need to do is parse out [DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org) categorizations. The amazon service uses DMOZ to get the categories anyway, and it's free (unlike AWIS). For example, parse out [this](http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=http://www.peta.org&start=0&type=more&all=no&cat=) link to get the categories for PETA.

If you're looking for parsing tools, I've quite enjoyed [Nokogiri](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri), but any web-parsing tool like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) works. I would parse it with something like:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open('<site>'))
doc.css('ol.dir li a').map {|item| [item.content]}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Alexa Webinfo API? It's easy to use and you can get the keywords as well as a lot of useful information about the link. (Plus it's part of AWS which means good speed and reliability)

General Info & Signup

> http://aws.amazon.com/awis/

Docs:

> http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/

Code Samples:

> http://aws.amazon.com/code?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1